# sInfo datatable parameter is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a search page in my appilcation where I display results in datatable. The results of search are fetched using ajax call. I have below properties for the datatable.

```
  SearchResultsTable = $("#SearchResultsTable").dataTable({
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "SearchAjaxResults.form",
    "bProcessing": false,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "oLanguage": {
        "sEmptyTable": "No data available",         
        "sLengthMenu" :" _MENU_ items per page",
        "sInfo": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries"
        },
    "sDom": 'tlp',
    "aoColumns": [null,null,null,{ "bVisible": false },{ "bVisible": false }],
    "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
        setHyperLinkOnColumns(nRow, aData);     
        return nRow;
    }
});
```

Everything works fine except for the sInfo option. Not able to see that parameter in the search page. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to change the "sDom" parameter to either 'ftlip' or 'tlip'. After changing the sDom parameter, able so see the sInfo values in the search page.

Comment: Thank you!! Modifying sDom did the trick.

"sDom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">'

Comment: To clarify, the "i" parameter next to "top" was the only one I needed, that's the one that is responsible for displaying the sInfo text as documented here: http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/options#sDom

Answer (score 0):

The value for sInfo should be at the top of the answer from your serversided code:

```
{
  "sEcho": 1,
  "iTotalRecords": "57",
  "iTotalDisplayRecords": "20",
  "aaData": [
    [
      "Gecko",
      "Firefox 1.0",
      "Win 98+ / OSX.2+",
      "1.7",
      "A"
    ],  ...
```

`iTotalRecords` are all entrys in your database.

`iTotalDisplayRecords` ist the number of records that are sent in your servers response, depending on pagination and/or filtering.

Its hard to give more details without seeing your server code.